# How to retrieve list of data in model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I have data in model and I used to store that data in session as below in controller

```
 if (providerListingModel.ServiceDetails != null && providerListingModel.ServiceDetails.Count > 0)
            Session["ServiceDetails"] = providerListingModel.ServiceDetails;
 else
            Session["ServiceDetails"] = null;
```

and for retrieving I had used the logic as

```
       if (Session["ServiceDetails"] != null)
        {
            if (providerListingModel.ServiceDetails == null)
            {
                List<ServiceDetail> sam = (List<ServiceDetail>)Session["ServiceDetails"];

                foreach (var items in sam)
                {
                    var sd = new ServiceDetail();
                    sd.Id = items.Id;
                    sd.CategoryServiceId = items.CategoryServiceId;
                    sd.ServiceType = items.ServiceType;
                    sd.ServicePrice = items.ServicePrice;
                    sd.IsSelected = items.IsSelected;
                    sd.ProviderListingId = providerListingModel.ProviderListingId;
                    providerListingModel.ServiceDetails.Add(sd);
                }
            }
            Session["ServiceDetails"] = null;
        }
```

The session contains data but on  providerListingModel.ServiceDetails.Add(sd); it throw null exception.
ServiceDetails is a class and it contains list of items

```
namespace xyz.DAL
{
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class ServiceDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProviderListingId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CategoryServiceId { get; set; }
    public string ServiceType { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ServicePrice { get; set; }
    public string CustomeService { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsSelected { get; set; }

    public virtual CategoryService CategoryService { get; set; }
    public virtual ProviderListing ProviderListing { get; set; }
}
}
```

am I missing some code?
As I am new I don't know what I am doing wrong

[image]
[image]

Comment: seems like providerListingModel.ServiceDetails value is null... list item should not be null, it should be empty collection to insert. so create new instance and add the item

Comment: Can you provide me 1 sample code

Comment: if(providerListingModel.ServiceDetails ==null) providerListingModel.ServiceDetails = new List<ServiceDetail>();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are inserting the item to null value, so it throws an error. Create new instance of the list and add an item to collection.

```
if(providerListingModel.ServiceDetails ==null)
  providerListingModel.ServiceDetails = new List<ServiceDetail>();
```

Comment: Just trying and will let u know in a moment

Comment: Is it possible that I put my code as   foreach (var items in sam)
                {
                    
                    providerListingModel.ServiceDetails.Add(Items);
                }